# Generate migrations for new tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I just created a model with some database structures I'd like to created

```
namespace Ability.Models
{
    public class Skill
    {
        [key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string SkillName { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        [key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Campus { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AbilityDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AbilityDbContext()
               : base("name= DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Skills)
            .WithMany(c => c.Teachers);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

However I have no idea how I can generate the migrations for these new tables. I thought it would give me a message when I try to Update-Database, so that I could use Add-Migration, but it just says

> No pending explicit migrations.

So my question is, how can I let the Entity framework do the work for me and create the correct migrations?

Answer (score 0):

Run the below commands in package manager console from visual studio under `Tools` menu item in order to have migration work

```
enable-migrations
add-migration AddTeacher
add-migration AddSkill
update-database
```

Also, if those entities are added new then you need to decorate them with `Table` attribute like

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Skills")]
    public class Skill
    {
        [key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string SkillName { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    }

   [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Teachers")]
    public class Teacher
    {
        [key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Campus { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This just created empty migration files.

Comment: @NicolasDecroos, my bad; you don't need those previous commands since you have already created entities. See edit in answer.

Comment: there's a typo in your code, it's "DataAnnotations", however the .Table is underlined in red saying the namespace does not exist in "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"

Comment: Yes, it's under `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace. Just type the `[Table("")]` and right click and choose resolve. That would solve the issue. At least you can put this much effort. Anyways see edit in answer.